Ошибка чтения Json в Python
Начал я делать сайт для мицценатов, инвесторов и авторов идей. И вдруг столкнулся с такой бедой: 
И я пытался использовать метод str(), но всё равно не работало! Та же ошибка!
Я лазил в Интернете но всё равно ничего не помогло. Помогите пожалуйста с проблемой!

Что не так?!

Вот код в Python:
import json, time, os
data = json.loads(open("Data.json", encoding="utf-8").read())
while True:
    password_input = input("Enter password: ")
    if password_input == str(data["password"]):
        print(f"Welcome, {data['name']}!")
        break
    else:
        counter = 3
        for i in range(counter):
            print(f"Invalid password! Wait: {str(counter)} seconds to continue.")
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system("cls")
            counter -= 1
        continue
print(f"Your status is: {data['status']}")
time.sleep(2)
input()

А вот Data.json:
[
    {
        "name": "PeterPervy",
        "password": "123456",
        "wallet": "500",
        "cryptowallet": "10",
        "transactions": [
            "37890",
            "12345",
            "67890"
        ],
        "status": "patron"
    },
    {
        "name": "PeterVtoroy",
        "password": "123456789",
        "wallet": "1000",
        "cryptowallet": "0",
        "transactions": [
            "37891",
            "123490",
            "67892489"
        ],
        "status": "investor"
        }
][]


data — это список. Доступ к элементам списка осуществляется по индексам, которые должны быть числами (от нуля до количества элементов в списке). При этом "password" очевидно не является числом и значит выражение data["password"] не имеет смысла

Но даже если не углубляться в питонячьи типы данных — вас чисто по-человечески должно было смутить хотя бы то, что в показанном вами файле есть целых два разных password, и вы должны ответить хотя бы сами себе, а какой конкретно password вы вознамерились прочитать — и потом каким-то образом объяснить своё намерение питону (и со status то же самое)

Квадратные скобки - список, фигурные скобки - словарь.
